# Openssl forgot password

Tags: linux, password, openssl

I’ve encrypted one file with des algorithm using openssl tool but I forgot my key .

Is there any way to recover that key or get any hint or something?

Comment: What would be the point of encrypting anything if it was trivially easy to guess the encryption key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a brute force attack trying every single combination of passwords should work...eventually. How much time do you have?

I presume you want to do this *quickly*, in which case the answer is almost certainly **No** there is no 'practical' way using the program and ciphertext/output.

Comment: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/popular-tools-for-brute-force-attacks/